# Contact form 7 in popover Bootstrap with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a contact form in the popover plugin from Bootstrap 3. It's initiated this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){   
            $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
                html : true,
                placement : 'bottom',
                trigger : 'click', 
                content: function() {
                  return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm displaying it this way:

```
<a class="call" rel="popover">call me back</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="84" title="Call me back"]' ); ?></div>
```

So when you click on the call me back button the contact form shows up. That's fine, it works. But when filling the form and sending it, there's no AJAX so the page refreshes. You have to hit the call me back button again to see the feedback from the form.

Is there a way that the feedback can be loaded in AJAX in the popover?

If I place the contact form code outside the popover tags, the AJAX works. Deleting *style="display: none"* in the *popover_content_wrapper* div fixes it too. But then you see the form without first clicking on the call me back button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced this problem and found a solution pretty quick.

You need to re-initialize CF7 form.

So you can try to change your code to the following:

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
  html : true,
  placement : 'bottom',
  trigger : 'click', 
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
  }
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  jQuery('.popover .wpcf7-form').wpcf7InitForm();
});
```